# Keep Alive Message WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

As I need to implement a sort of "Keep-Alive" functionality to my server-side, I'm wondering how to do so.

- Option 1: create a ping method which is called every 10th Minute by the client
- Option 2: Let WCF handle this

I've read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732515/keepalive-with-wcf-and-tcp), and it explains alot of what I'm trying to achieve. My only problem is that I use `WsHttp` binding with `Transport` as Security, and therefore not allowed to set `reliableSession enabled=true`.

From what I suspect, if this `enabled=true`, is set to false, the `inactivityTimeout=00:15:00` is invalid, and will not be used by WCF? Am I correct? Any other approaches that I can use?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read [Reliable Sessions Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733136%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Custom Binding Reliable Session over HTTPS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395197%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?